# Who are the authors of and what are the significances of "Eka Sloki Ramayana" , "Eka Sloki Bhagawatam" and the like?

Tags: scripture, ramayana, bhagavata-purana, shloka, saint

As the name suggests,the [Eka Sloki Ramayana](http://www.hindupedia.com/en/Eka_Sloki_Ramayan) is the whole story of Ramayana told in just one sloka/verse:

> aadau raama tapovanaadi gamanam hatvaa mrugam kaanchanam
>   vaidehee
>   haraNam jaTaayu maraNam sugreeva sambhaash aNam |
>   baalee nigrahaNam
>   samudra taraNam lankaapuree daahanam
>   pashchaat raavaNa kumbhakarNa
>   hananametaddhi raamaa yaNam 
>   ekashlokee raamaayaNam sampoorNam
>   ||

Meaning-

> Once Rama went to forest, He chased the deer, Sitha was kidnapped,
>   Jatayu was killed, There were talks with Sugreeva, Bali was killed,
>   The sea was crossed, Lanka was burnt, And later Ravana and Kumbha
>   karna, Were also killed. This in short is the story of Ramayanam.

Similarly we have the [Eka Sloki Bhagwatam](http://www.hindupedia.com/en/Eka_Sloki_Bhagawatham) which narrates the entire Bhagwata Purana in just one sloka/verse:

> Aadhou devaki devi garbha jananam, Gopi gruhe palanam, Mayaa poothana
>   jeevithaa apaharanam, govardhanodharanam, Kamsa chedana, kouravadi
>   hananam, kunthi sutha palanam, Ethad bhagawatham purana kaditham sri
>   Krishna leelamrutham

Meaning-

> Born to queen Devaki, Brought up by Gopis, Took out the life of Ogress
>   Poothana, Lifted the Govardhana mountain, Beheaded his uncle Kamsa,
>   Helped in killing the Kouravas, And looked after the children of
>   Kunthi. This is in short the ancient story of Bhagawatha, Which
>   describes the nectar like play of Lord Krishna

.

We also have a "Sapta Sloki Gita" and a "Chatusloki Bhagawtam" ,the later is given below:

[image]

Q1) Who are the authors of the "Eka Sloki Ramayana" and the "Eka Sloki Bhagawtam"?

Q2) What are their significance? Does it mean that reading those short verses are equivalent (in merit) to reading the respective entire texts or something of that sort?

Comment: @Rickross - I think "eka shloki" means only one shloka and "ChatuhaShloki " means set of 4 shlokas. So IMO the questions should be " who composed "ChatuhShloki Ramayana"and "ChatuhShloki Bhagvatam" .

Comment: @SwiftPushkar I can actually see two slokas/verses.So ,don't know why they are called eka Sloki.But definitely there r no 4 verses in them.And, they r called eka sloki only.See here:http://joyfulslokas.blogspot.in/2011/11/eka-sloki-ramayanam.html

Comment: @UdayKrishna I don't think it was Adi Shankara who composed them but let's wait for answers.

Comment: @Rickross - Oh , on that site they haven't assigned numbers to each individual shloka.So they can say it as eka shloki , that also is right.But the image provided by you states chathushloki which I think is general standard and more appropriate.

Comment: The image is of the Chautsloki Bhagwatam only.That was only provided as an additional example ,but my questions are actually on the Eka Sloki ones.I have given link for both of them.

Comment: @UdayKrishna Ok thanks ,but unfortunately i am asking about the eka sloki ones.

Comment: @UdayKrishna If you know you can answer about the chatuslokis as well..because my Q title says "...and the likes"..so i don't have problems with that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> **अहमेवासमेवाग्रे नान्यद् यत सद्सत परम । पाश्र्चादहं यदेतच्च योsवशिष्येत**
>   **सोS स्मयहम ।।32।।**
>
> **ऋतेSर्थं यत प्रतीयेत न प्रतीयेत चात्मनि । तद्वीद्यादात्मनो  मायां**
>   **यथाSS भासो यथा तमः ।।33।।**
>
> **यथा महान्ति भूतानि भुतेषूच्चावचेष्वनु । प्रविष्टन्यप्राविष्टयानि तथा**
>   **तेषु न तेष्वहम ।।34।।**
>
> **एतावदेव जिज्ञास्यम तत्वजिज्ञासुनाSSत्मनः । भवान कल्पविकल्पेषु न**
>   **विमुह्यति कहिर्चित ।।35।।**
>
> **Meaning** - Only I was present before this universe. Without me there were no  "Sthula , Sukashma or reason for both ie."Adanyana" (
>   स्थूल ,सूक्ष्म & अज्ञान) .What ever is everything , is me itself.Also
>   what will remain after "Pralaya (प्रलय) is  only me.
>
> As there is only one moon only , but due to error in our eye it looks
>   as two moons , although even  there is nothing , but it feels in
>   "Paramatma" (supreme soul) , as residing among "Nakshtras" (नक्षत्र) 
>   , but won't get seen. The atma (आत्मा) is like that ,this is my "Maya"
>
> In the big & small bodies of living beings who are controlled by
>   "Panchamahabutas" (पंचमहाभूत) , it  appeares as I have entered into
>   them in the form of "Atma"(soul).But if you look from " Atmadrushti
>   (आत्मदृष्टि), as there is nothing but myself, I do not enter into
>   those bodies.
>
> A wise person should know this - "that which is ever present
>   everywhere"   is the "Atmatatva"(आत्मतत्व) , by the  way of
>   "Ananvayavyatirek (अन्वयव्यतिरेक)

I am giving the explanation about **"Chatuhshloki Bhagvat"**  as described in  [**Shreemad Bhagvat Purana**](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/2/9/33)  . We find  chtuhshloki bhagvat in  ( 2 skanda chapter 9  shlokas 32-35)   Bhagvat purana where **"Bhagvan" (supreme lord) Shree Vishnu or  Shree Krishna describing this  shlokas to "Brahamdeva".**
So "Chatuhshloki bhagvat " is **narrated by supreme Bhagvan** himself. So these are called as so.

Regarding your question about the significance of this "Chatuhshloki Bhagvat"  this is given in same chapter in the next shloka.

> **ऐतमन्त समतिष्ठ परमेंण समाधिना । भवान** **कल्पविकल्पेशु न विमुह्यति**
>   **कहिर्चित ।। 36।।**
>
> **Meaning** - O brahmadeva , you by steadyness (Samadhi ) believe
>   completly to this "Siddhanta"(सिध्दांत) और law , there by you will not
>   get involved in any "Moha" (मोह) in any of the "kalpas" .

**As we can see , this is the pure essence or ultimate teaching of shreemad bhagvat purana.We can say that this method of describing events in large texts into very few shlokas is useful in presenting the ultimate message or core message of that perticular book or text.It also enables the reader with that.Also by this method a story or message can be presented without the need of any interpreter or reading the whole text**

Comment: Thanks.So it seems the "eka slokis" are also part of some Puranas.

Comment: @Rickross - Yes ,  "Chatuhshloki Bhagvat" is part of puranas. But will look for Ramayana whether it is part of any purana or not.:)

Comment: @Rickross The answer has mentioned the four conseutive slokas of Bhagavatam. But who called it Chatuhsloki Bhagavatam is not clear to me from this,Mahaprabhu mentions the term "Chatuhsloki' BTW.

Comment: This is the best answer I got so far (in fact the only one) .. If u can write an answer and if it is better than this one then I may accept urs @commonman

Comment: Okay @Rickross I shall try

Comment: @Rickross did you find source of eka sloki/chatursloki Ramayana?

Comment: @RishX no not yet

Comment: @Rickross ok. Plz notify me if you do.

Comment: @RishX Okay I will do that.