# Who compiled Saptasloki Gita and Chatuhsloki Bhagavata?

Tags: bhagavad-gita, bhagavata-purana

In the Chatuhsloki Bhagavata and Saptasloki Gita which quotes **SEVEN** slokas from Srimad-Bhagavatam and Srimad-Bhagavad-Gita respectively, I found NO mention of the words 'Vishnu' and 'Krishna'!

But these are considered to be essences of Bhagavata and Gita respectively.

Who compiled these two?

**UPDATE**

The answer to the question: [Who are the authors of and what are the significances of "Eka Sloki Ramayana" , "Eka Sloki Bhagawatam" and the like?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/15797/who-are-the-authors-of-and-what-are-the-significances-of-eka-sloki-ramayana) mentons the four consecutive slokas of Srimad-Bhagavatam which are the four slokas of the Chatuhsloki Bhagavata.But Chatuhsloki Bhagavatam given in Ahnikkrittya by Shyamacharan Kaviratna Vidyavaridhi gives **SEVEN** slokas.

Mahaprabhu has mentioned the word 'Chatuhsloki' by the way.So there must had been some reference somewhere in the scriptures of these slolkas being mentioned as 'Chatuhsloki'.

Ahnikkrittya is a very famous book and the writer and compilervwas a very very renowned scholar.

Comment: could you please provide the exact verses?

Comment: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/15797/who-are-the-authors-of-and-what-are-the-significances-of-eka-sloki-ramayana

Answer (score 4):

I will say about Bhagavatam.

We see in SB 12.13.19

> I meditate upon that pure and spotless Supreme Absolute Truth, who is
>   free from suffering and death and who in the beginning personally
>   revealed this incomparable torchlight of knowledge to Brahmā. Brahmā
>   then spoke it to the sage Nārada, who narrated it to Kṛṣṇa-dvaipāyana
>   Vyāsa. Śrīla Vyāsa revealed this Bhāgavatam to the greatest of sages,
>   Śukadeva Gosvāmī, and Śukadeva mercifully spoke it to Mahārāja
>   Parīkṣit.

We find in

SB 2.9.44-45:(or 43-44 depending on numbering)

> (44) This story of the Fortunate One, the Bhâgavata Purâna, that with
>   its ten characteristics was explained by the Supreme
>   Lord, was thereupon explained by the creator of the universe to his
>   son [Nârada]. (45) On the bank of the Sarasvatî Nârada [in his turn]
>   instructed this Supreme Spirituality to the great sage, the meditative
>   Vyâsadeva who is of an unlimited potency, oh King.

The actual verses spoken by Supreme Lord to Brahma are 2.9.30-36/2.9.31-37 depending on how verses are split.

Now, I quote from [Hindu Theology in Early Modern South Asia: The Rise of Devotionalism and the Politics of Genealogy (Oxford Theology and Religion Monographs)](https://www.amazon.in/Hindu-Theology-Early-Modern-South/dp/0198709269)

> The BhaPu, second book, chapter nine, relates the following story as
>   the background of the Catuhslokibhagavata, that is, 2.9.32-35.
>   Before the creation of the universe, Brahma was born on a lotus flower
>   stemming from the navel of Garbhodakaiayi Vishnu'. Brahma tried to
>   trace the origin of the lotus on which he was sitting, but he was not
>   successful. While contemplating the matter of creation, he heard the
>   sixteenth and the twenty-first syllables of the Sanskrit alphabets,
>   namely, ta and pa, which, in combination, mean an injunction, 'You
>   should perform austerity.'" He looked for the speaker of the
>   injunction, but he was again unsuccessful. Subsequently, he sat down
>   on the lotus and engaged in performing austerity in the form of
>   meditation. After Brahma had meditated for a thousand years," Vishnu
>   appeared." He praised
>   Brahma for his performance of austerity and gave him a boon: to ask
>   whatever he desired. In response, Brahma asked the following four
>   questions. According to Joshi, these four questions correspond to
>   BhaPu 2.9.25-28: (1) What is the nature of your subtle and gross form?
>   (2) How can I understand the nature of your Maya, Yogamaya and their
>   effects? (3) How do you play in the universe covered by Maya and
>   YogaMaya (4) What is that action by which I will not be bound while
>   creating the universe? (Joshi 1974:27-28) **Vishnu replied to this
>   question in seven verses, i.e. BhiPu 2.9.30-36, which includes the
>   CaSloBha. Therefore in Vallabha's Subodhini, he argues that BhaPu 2.9.30-36 should be  taken as one section, constituting the Saptashlokibhagavata. In contrast, Sridhara, Jiva, 
>    ViSvanatha, and Suka-deva take 2.9.32-35 to be the real answer to Brahma's four questions (Joshi 1934: 26-27)** In BhaPu 2.9.30, the Lord says that He will answer
>   Brahma's questions in terms of knowledge (jnana), realization
>   (vijnana), secret (rahasya), and auxiliary (tadanga).'7 These four
>   points correspond to verses 32 to 35. In verse 31, the Lord says that
>   these four points are revealed to Brahma through His favor
>   (madanugrahat). Therefore, it is clear that what He says in the
>   following four verses is to be understood as a revelation by Visual,
>   to Brahma in the form of His favor.

Further quoting from same book,

> **Sridhara was the first commentator to identify these four verses as
>   the original revelation.** Chaitanya follows him since he accepted
>   Sridhara as the best commentator on Bhagavatam. This identification of
>   the four verses as the original revelation is found in **Sridhara's
>   commentary on Bha Pur 2.9.43: "[Brahma] spoke in detail [to Narada]
>   what the Lord spoke [to him] briefly in four verses in which the
>   topics expressed as ten characteristics are known**"

I found one reference to catuh shloki in Bhagavata Mahatmya of Padma Purana.(6.194.63-71)

> कुमारा ऊचुः  वेदोपनिषदां साराज्जाता भागवती कथा  अत्युत्तमा ततो भाति
>   पृथग्भूता फलोन्नतिः ६३ आमूलाग्रं रसोस्त्येव रसालस्य यथा फले  पृथग्भूतं
>   तु पानेन यथा विश्वमनोहरः ६४ यथा दुग्धेस्थितं सर्पिर्न च
>   स्वादूपकल्प्यते  पृथग्भूतं तु तद्दिव्यं देवानां प्रीतिवर्द्धनम् ६५
>   इक्षुष्विवादिमध्यांतं शर्करा व्याप्य तिष्ठति  पृथग्भूता तु सा मिष्टा
>   तथा भागवती कथा ६६ श्रीमद्भागवतं नाम पुराणं रसमेव हि 
>   भक्तिज्ञानविरागाणां सौख्यायैव प्रकाशितम् ६७ **कृष्णेन ब्रह्मणे
>   नाभिकंजस्थाय हृदैव हि  *तच्चतुःश्लोकमखिलं* ब्रह्मैव प्रतिभासते** ६८ तुभ्यं
>   च ब्रह्मणा प्रोक्तं तच्चरित्रनिदर्शनम्  त्वयापि व्यासदेवाय प्रोक्तं
>   तत्तापहानये ६९ यदीयस्मरणात्सद्यो निर्विण्णो बादरायणः  चकार
>   महदाख्यातुमात्माराम मनोहरम् ७० अत्र ते विस्मयः केन येन पृच्छेः पुनः
>   पुनः  श्रीमद्भागवतं शास्त्रं क्षमं कृष्णानुकर्षणे ७१
>
> kumārā ūcuḥ  vedopaniṣadāṃ sārājjātā bhāgavatī kathā  atyuttamā tato
>   bhāti pṛthagbhūtā phalonnatiḥ 63 āmūlāgraṃ rasostyeva rasālasya yathā
>   phale  pṛthagbhūtaṃ tu pānena yathā viśvamanoharaḥ 64 yathā
>   dugdhesthitaṃ sarpirna ca svādūpakalpyate  pṛthagbhūtaṃ tu taddivyaṃ
>   devānāṃ prītivarddhanam 65 ikṣuṣvivādimadhyāṃtaṃ śarkarā vyāpya
>   tiṣṭhati  pṛthagbhūtā tu sā miṣṭā tathā bhāgavatī kathā 66
>   śrīmadbhāgavataṃ nāma purāṇaṃ rasameva hi  bhaktijñānavirāgāṇāṃ
>   saukhyāyaiva prakāśitam 67 **kṛṣṇena brahmaṇe nābhikaṃjasthāya hṛdaiva
>   hi  *taccatuḥśloka*makhilaṃ brahmaiva pratibhāsate** 68 tubhyaṃ ca
>   brahmaṇā proktaṃ taccaritranidarśanam  tvayāpi vyāsadevāya proktaṃ
>   tattāpahānaye 69 yadīyasmaraṇātsadyo nirviṇṇo bādarāyaṇaḥ  cakāra
>   mahadākhyātumātmārāma manoharam 70 atra te vismayaḥ kena yena pṛccheḥ
>   punaḥ punaḥ  śrīmadbhāgavataṃ śāstraṃ kṣamaṃ kṛṣṇānukarṣaṇe 71
>
> The Bhagavata-account has risen from the quintessence of the Vedas and
>   the Upanisads. Therefore, it appears to be the best, and the rise of
>   fruit is different. As the taste is present in a mango fruit from the
>   bottom to the top, but is different when separated and drunk, and
>   delights all, as ghee present in milk is not thought to be pleasant,
>   but when separated is divine, and increases the joy of gods, as sugar
>   remains pervading the bottom, the middle and the end (i.e. the top) of
>   a sugarcane, and is sweet when separated, so is Bhagavata-story. The
>   Purana named Srimad Bhagavata is relish itself; it is manifested for
>   the happiness of Bhakti, Jnana and Vairagya to **Brahma, remaining in
>   the lotus born from his navel, by Krsna. *The four-versed* (summary)
>   of it appears to be the entire Brahman.** That account was narrated to
>   you by Brahma. You also narrated it to Vyasadeva, to destroy torment.
>   By remembering it Badarayana (Vyasa) instantly became free from lamentation; and
>   in a manner delighting the soul, composed (the work of) the great
>   name. Due to what are you amazed, that you are asking again and again?
>   The holy text of Srimad Bhagavata is capable of attracting Krsna.

**Madhvacharya & Vijayadhwaja of Madhva school doesn't identify them as catuh/sapta shloki but comment upon them.**

The book also does a comparative study of commentaries of Sridhara, Jiva and Madhva&Vijayadhwaja.

On the first of the catuh shloki (2.9.32):

[image]

Comment: Thnx for your answer